# Neo4j Spring SocketTimeoutError

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I'm using:

- neo4j 1.8.2
- spring 3.1.1
- spring-data-neo4j 2.1.0
- spring-data-neo4j-rest 2.1.0

In my neo4j instance I have:

- 219 nodes
- 1838 properties
- 592 relationships

In my code I want to search for friends of friends; in orde to do it I wrote this code:

```
@Query(value = "START n = node({userStartId}) "
+ "MATCH n-[:OPINION_LEADER_INFLUENCE*2..]->friend_of_friend "
+ "WHERE not(n-[:OPINION_LEADER_INFLUENCE]->friend_of_friend) "
+ "and id(n) <> id(friend_of_friend) "
+ "RETURN COUNT (distinct friend_of_friend)")
public int getFriendOfFriendNumber(@Param("userStartId") long userStartId)
```

When I executed it I got a SocketTimeoutException
I tried to execute the query directly on neo4j dashboard; the executed query is the following one:

```
START n = node(111) 
MATCH n-[:OPINION_LEADER_INFLUENCE*2..]->friend_of_friend 
WHERE not(n-[:OPINION_LEADER_INFLUENCE]->friend_of_friend) 
and id(n) <> id(friend_of_friend) 
RETURN COUNT (distinct friend_of_friend)
```

Executing it on the neo4j dashboard I took around 10 minutes in order to be executed (this is the reason I got the error)

May you kindly tell me how I can prevent the error?

Is there any tuning I should do in neo4j?

Should I modify the query?

How can I set the timeout for the Jersey?

Thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

It was the query; I modified it in this way:

```
START n = node(111)
MATCH n-[:OPINION_LEADER_INFLUENCE*2..2]-friend_of_friend 
WHERE not(n-[:OPINION_LEADER_INFLUENCE]-friend_of_friend)
and id(n) <> id(friend_of_friend) 
RETURN COUNT (distinct friend_of_friend), friend_of_friend.user_id
```

Angelo